# Making slider, jquery doesnt work inside if()

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I have problem changing css value to xy;
I am trying to make slider, slider works, but when I need to change margin value to move from last picture to first one nothing changes, margin values just increases, I tried to debugg it with putting alert inside if statement and It alerted me, but css margin value havent changed. When I put

```
$("#slideshow .slides").css({'margin-left':'0px'});
```

in console it changes the value like it should.
Can you guys help me, I cant see why it isnt working.
ps is there any way to debugg js?

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {   
    var numOfPic=$('.slides li').length;    
    var cnt=0;

        $("#arrows .left_arrow").click(function(){
        $("#slideshow .slides").animate({
                'margin-left': '-=1200px'});
                cnt++;
            if(cnt>=numOfPic)
            {
                $("#slideshow .slides").css({
                'margin-left':'0px'});
            }
        });
```

CSS

```
    #slideshow .slides
{
    display:block;
    width:7200px;
    height:675px;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding:0;
}

    #slideshow .slide
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:1200px;
    height:675px;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that:  'margin-left': '-=1200px'} be  'margin-left': '-1200px'} ?

Comment: no, every time it adds -1200 to existing value, if there is onli -1200 it would always stay on one picture, thats not problem, problem is part inside if statement.

Comment: animate and css() will conflict with each other

Comment: ok so basicly problem is that animate is slover than css so i need to pot eather both to css or animate to fix it: